# ¿Como llenar un campo con "mensajes" para un chat?

Tags: netbeans, java-swing

Estoy realizando un Chat muy casero. La tengo conectada a la BD Sql Server (por práctica. Poco viable lo sé) para guardar los mensajes enviados y consultarlos en el SGBD para corroborar que se guardan correctamente.

El problema viene acá
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no logro que mensaje enviado se quede ahí fijo (o hasta arriba) en el textBox superior, se reemplaza con el nuevo mensaje.

El método que uso para "llenar" el textBox superior es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como podría hacer esa parte?
trabajo con un textBox para eso, soy nuevo en esto de la interfaz.

(Después lo conectaré con hilos para el segundo usuario).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aconsejo que si vas a utilizar tu chat para el envio de solo mensajes utilices un `JTextArea` los diálogos los vas añadiendo asi:

```
JTextArea.append(" tu mensaje"+"\n");
```

El carácter `"\n"` es para que hagas un salto de linea cada vez que añadas un nuevo mensaje al textArea.

Si quieres algo mas personalizado como imagenes y botones, utiliza un JTextPane.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir acumulando el string que quieres escribir. En tu caso:

```
while(rs.next()){
    mensaje += rs.getString("MENSAJE"); //acumulamos en mensaje
    txtVentanaChatComp.setText(mensaje);
}
```

Para la posición del texto dentro de la ventana de texto, tendrás que modificar las propiedades del comoponente para indicar donde quieres que se coloque el texto (arriba, abajo, izquierda, derecha, centro, etc.).

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.